# Count not giving right results with three joins

Tags: mysql, count

I have three tables (MySQL)

forum: each line in this table is a comment in the forum related to the match by static_id and related to the author by user_id

```
|match_static_id| date | time | comments | user_id |
```

matches: this table contains matches with all its information

```
| static_id | localteam_name | visitorteam_name | date | time |.......
```

iddaa : this table contains a code for each match (some matches do not have codes here)

```
|match_static_id| iddaa_code |
```

I make a query like following:

```
SELECT  forum.match_static_id, forum.date, forum.time,
count(forum.comments) 'comments_no', matches.*, users.username, iddaa.iddaa_code
FROM forum
INNER JOIN matches ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_id
INNER JOIN users on forum.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN iddaa on forum.match_static_id = iddaa.match_static_id
GROUP BY forum.match_static_id 
ORDER BY forum.date DESC, forum.time DESC
```

the query work as I want (I get the match information, iddaa code for the match if there is one, and the author of the comment(last comment) ).
The problem is in the "count function" I should get the number of the comments related to the same match bur the query returned (double of each value) 
for example if I have 5 comments for a match it returns 10
I want to know if all parts of my query is right and any help will be good?

Comment: Wont the left join always return same amount in this count? Try without a left join.

Comment: I can not remove left join it is important to get the value of iddaa for each match. the problem in iddaa query, I know that but I need a workaround way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be wrapped in a sub query? Its hard when i dont have the table def + data.

```
SELECT Sub.*, COUNT(1) 'comments_no'
FROM
(
SELECT  forum.match_static_id, forum.date, forum.time,
matches.*, users.username, iddaa.iddaa_code
FROM forum
INNER JOIN matches ON forum.match_static_id = matches.static_id
INNER JOIN users on forum.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY forum.match_static_id
) Sub
LEFT JOIN iddaa on Sub.match_static_id = iddaa.match_static_id
ORDER BY forum.date DESC, forum.time DESC
```

Comment: You may have to write Count(iddaa.Comments) to get the count